# How to fix error in if statement and when searching in an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

my Library calss need to be corrected , I wrote the error comments next to the wanted lines ... I used this: // ***** to show the error comments in eclipse. The main method of class Library must not modify , you just modify the subclasses under class Library ... I did like this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {   

    ArrayList <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String adress;

    pubilc void Library(String t){ // ***** it says - Syntax error on token "pubilc", public expected- This method has a constructor name

        this.adress=t;

    }

    public void addBook(String r){
        list.add(r);
    }
    public static void printOpeningHours(){
        System.out.println("Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm.");

    }
    public void printAddress(){
        System.out.println(adress);

    }
    public void borrowBook(String k){
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if (list.get(i).equals(k)){
        System.out.println("You successfully borrowed The Lord of the Rings");
        list.remove(get(i)); // ***** it says The method get(int) is undefined for the type Library
        }else{
        System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
        }

    }
    }
    public void printAvailableBooks(){
        System.out.println(list);

    }
    public void returnBook(String r){
        for (String b : list){
            if (b.get(b).equals(r)){ // ***** The method get(String) is undefined for the type String 
                return b; // ***** Void methods cannot return a value
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Lord of the Ring");

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create two libraries
         Library firstLibrary = new Library("10 Main St."); // ***** The constructor Library(String) is undefined
         Library secondLibrary = new Library("228 Liberty St.");  // ***** The constructor Library(String) is undefined

        // Add four books to the first library
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code")); // ***** The method addBook(String) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("Le Petit Prince")); // ***** The method addBook(String) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("A Tale of Two Cities")); // ***** The method addBook(String) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
        firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings")); // ***** The method addBook(String) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments (Book)

        // Print opening hours and the addresses
        System.out.println("Library hours:");
        printOpeningHours();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Library addresses:");
        firstLibrary.printAddress();
        secondLibrary.printAddress();
        System.out.println();

        // Try to borrow The Lords of the Rings from both libraries
        System.out.println("Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        firstLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of all available books from both libraries
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Books available in the second library:");
        secondLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
        System.out.println();

        // Return The Lords of the Rings to the first library
        System.out.println("Returning The Lord of the Rings:");
        firstLibrary.returnBook("The Lord of the Rings");
        System.out.println();

        // Print the titles of available from the first library
        System.out.println("Books available in the first library:");
        firstLibrary.printAvailableBooks();
    }
}
```

The output should be like this :

```
Library hours:
Libraries are open daily from 9am to 5pm.
Library addresses:
10 Main St.
228 Liberty St.
Borrowing The Lord of the Rings:
You successfully borrowed The Lord of the Rings
Sorry, this book is already borrowed.
Sorry, this book is not in our catalog.
Books available in the first library:
The Da Vinci Code
Le Petit Prince
A Tale of Two Cities
Books available in the second library:
No book in catalog
Returning The Lord of the Rings:
You successfully returned The Lord of the Rings
Books available in the first library:
The Da Vinci Code
Le Petit Prince
A Tale of Two Cities
The Lord of the Rings
```

Do you have any idea to correct the code to get the desired output ...
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these errors are very self-explanatory if you read them.

```
Syntax error on token "pubilc", public expected- This method has a constructor name
```

You spelled `public` wrong, and there should be no return type on a constructor.

---

```
The method get(int) is undefined for the type Library
```

`list.remove(get(i));` should just be `list.remove(i);` or `list.remove(list.get(i));`

---

```
The method get(String) is undefined for the type String
```

`if (b.get(b).equals(r))` should just be `if(b.equals(r))`

---

```
Void methods cannot return a value
```

If you want `returnBook()` to return a `String`, the method signature should be:

```
public String returnBook(String r)
```

and get rid of the line `return;` after `return b;`, it is dead code.

---

```
The constructor Library(String) is undefined
```

This will be fixed once you fix your `Library` constructor.

---

```
The method addBook(String) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments (Book)
```

You don't have an `addBook` method that takes a `Book`, only one that takes a `String`, if you want to pass in a `Book`, you need to make a method for that.

Comment: thank you very much .. I did all you mentioned ... you said : " You don't have an addBook method that takes a Book, only one that takes a String, if you want to pass in a Book, you need to make a method for that. " I have Book class and I did program it and it is correct ...

Comment: Yes, your Library class has `addBook(String)`, but it doesn't have `addBook(Book)`. You are trying to pass a Book in on this line: `firstLibrary.addBook(new Book("The Da Vinci Code"));`, but your method only takes a string like `firstLibrary.addBook("The Da Vinci Code");`

Comment: so I have to make a class called : public void addBook(Book n) ... is it correct?

Comment: A *method*, not a class, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

first error:

```
public void Library(String t){
  this.adress=t;
}
```

the error means that this method had the same name as the class. but only constructors can have the same name as class. the correct syntax to define constuctor is

```
public Library(String t){
  this.adress=t;
}
```

the must not be 'return type' definition.

second error:

```
list.remove(list.get(i));
```

Comment: You dont need to do `list.remove(list.get(i));` All you need to do is `list.remove(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Why I can't explain you right now, but I got that same problem ones. But the solution is the following:

```
public void borrowBook(String k){
    for (int i=list.size()-1;i>=0; i--){
        if (list.get(i).equals(k)){
            System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + r);
            list.remove(i); 
        }else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public void borrowBook(String k){
    for (int i=list.size()-1;i>=0; i--){
        if (list.get(i).equals(k)){
            System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + r);
            String book = list.get(i); 
            list.remove(book);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, this book is already borrowed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you brother ... if you see the output I wrote you will see that secondLibrary.borrowBook("The Lord of the Rings"); should return  : Sorry, this book is not in our catalog..... How to get that output ???

Comment: you have :  System.out.println("You successfully borrowed " + r); what is r ? there is no r in the BorrowBook method

Comment: It has to be a 'k'. It's shows what book you borrowed. So, if the list contains the book and then removes it. you "borrowed" the book.